# Getting "java.sql.SQLException:Transactions not supported" Error while calling Spring Boot Rest API with Informix Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere, informix

I Have Created a Simple Spring boot Rest Application which can get/post the data to the Informix Database.

While Calling the Rest API getting below mentioned Error Message, I have searched for root cause  about the same but not found any sources,

Appreciate help on this, Here is the Configuration  and code which I have created:

> *application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:informix-sqli://XXXX:XXXX/localdb:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_xxxxx
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

> Along with spring starter web, Data JPA, Dev Tools Added below Additional Dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;
    
    @GetMapping("/user/{userId}")
    public void getUserDetails(@PathVariable Long countryId) {
      Optional<webCountry> country = repository.findById(countryId);
      System.out.println(country);
    }
    
    @PostMapping(path="/saveuser")
    public void saveUser(@RequestBody UserEntity user) {
        repository.save(data);
    }
}
```

> Repository Interface

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

}
```

> While Calling the Get API from post Man getting Below Error Message

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: ] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Transactions not supported
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setAutoCommit(IfxSqliConnect.java:2426) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:414) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:184) ~[spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:574) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:361) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 3):

Informix provides four different database types:

- Unlogged
- Buffered logging
- Unbuffered logging
- Unbuffered logging MODE ANSI

An unlogged database has no transaction log and hence does not support transactions.  All the other types support transactions; the differences between the varieties aren't relevant now.

The default type of database when you say `CREATE DATABASE xyz` is an unlogged database.  You have to say `WITH LOG` or `WITH BUFFERED LOG` or `WITH LOG MODE ANSI` to create a database with a transaction log.

Judging from the error message, the database you're using was created without transactions.

If necessary  (and it probably is necessary), a DBSA (database system administrator — usually, that means someone with the privileges to work as user `informix`) can change the logging mode. Switching to buffered logging is probably suitable.  A DBSA can either use `ontape` to change the mode while performing a server backup, or use `ondblog` (but a backup is a good idea even so):

```
ontape -s -B xyz

ondblog buf xyz
```

See [Manage the database-logging mode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0670.htm) for more details.

When you attempt to start a transaction in an unlogged Informix database, the error message generated is:

```
-256 Transaction not available.
```

The Informix `finderr` command shows:

```
$ finderr -256
-256    Transaction not available.

You cannot begin a transaction in this database because it does not
have a transaction log. In order to support transactions, you must
start a transaction log. Refer to your Administrator's Guide for
information on how to start a transaction log.

$
```

Comment: The command CREATE DATABASE tram_des2 WITH BUFFERED LOG; worked for my.

Answer (score 2):

This can have one or more of the following causes:

- IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
- Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by the local DNS server.
- Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
- DB server is down.
- DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
- DB server has run out of connections.

Comment: How does any of this relate to the exception reported in the question title: `java.sql.SQLException: Transactions not supported`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you can try by adding @Transactional annotation to your repository.
refer: https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring